# PlanningCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek() makes handlers handle events twice

Tags: sapui5

I have a certain setup in which after I call PlanningCalendar's setFirstDateOfWeek() each calendar event is triggered twice.

**Is there a special logic of this function?**

I have tried replicating the issue by starting with an exmaple but with no success.

What I do is in onInit() I wait an async function in whose .then() I call the setFirstDayOfWeek(). After that all events like onSelectAppointment() are triggered twice.

Here is the sample:

```
    async function simpleFunc() {
        console.log("SimpleFunc");
    }

    function setFirstDay() {
        let pc = context.byId("PC1");
        pc.setFirstDayOfWeek(0);
    }

    return Controller.extend("sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendarWithLegend.Page", {

        onInit: function () {
            // create model
            var oModel = new JSONModel();

            this.getView().setModel(oModel);

            var oStateModel = new JSONModel();
            oStateModel.setData({
                legendShown: false
            });

            var context;
            context = this;

            this.byId("PC1").setBuiltInViews(["Week", "One Month"]);
            this.byId("PC1").setStartDate(new Date());

            simpleFunc().then(() => {
                setFirstDay();
            });
            
            this.getView().setModel(oStateModel, "stateModel");
        },

        onSelectAppointment: function() {
            console.log("selected");
        },
```

In my local setup the only difference is that I don't define the context like in the code snipet, but instead, I have a ContextUtils.js file through which I get the context:

```
  sap.ui.define([], function () {
  "use strict";

  var CONTEXT;

  return {
    get: function () {
      return CONTEXT;
    },
    set: function (context) {
      CONTEXT = context;
    },
  };
});
```

EDIT: If, in my program, I call setFirstDayOfWeek() twice, then my handlers are called three times. So, with each setFirstDayOfWeek, I get one more handler.